# Align rotation to target using the normal of one of the faces of the rotating object

Tags: transforms, snapping, transform-orientation

Hello Blender community,

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of days and decided it was time to seek help from more seasoned veterans!

I am building a hollow ring segmented into 8 identical segments that will snap together using snap joints.  I have created the male end of a segment. Now, I want to create the female end of the joint by duplicating the object and adding a boolean modifier with the male end as the target to get that perfect fit (I may use a displace modifier so that there is some wiggle room for the joints).  My problem arises when I am attempting to snap 2 segments together as one would do once the objects were printed.[image]

The end result should look something like this where I eyeballed the rotation transformation.  Of course, this might work, but ideally, I coulld guarantee exactness by utilizing the snapping feature.

[image]

I have tried a number of things to get the ends to snap together with the correct alignment and orientation.  Firstly, I tried simply snapping with "Face project" and "Align rotation to target".  Since the orientation of the entire object is different from the orientation of the that I want to snap it, this is the result:

[image]

as you can see, the Z orientation of the snapped segment was pointing up so when it is snapped, it lines up with the normal of the target face and causes the entire segment to turn on its side.  This made me think that I need to create a custom orientation where the Z axis points into the object that I am snapping.

To do this, I created a face on each segment using the loop of vertices.  You can see the faces that I created in the first image. Each face has 2 vertices circled in green and in the male end on the right side of the first image you can see the red face which indicates the orientation of the faces normal.  I created a custom orientation called "Face" with the red face.

[image]

Finally, in object mode, I selected Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation and then reattempted snapped with the same settings selected.  The result was the following:

[image]

I have also tried applying the rotation transformation after aligning the transform to the Face orientation and then snapping.   This is the result.

[image]

At this point I have run out of ideas and do not know what else I can try.  Any help or suggestions on this is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I am adding a Google Drive link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g3cnXaITcvl6UCfjE0kgLVJ731bocgkS/view?usp=sharing) to my .blend file.  I am working with `Torus.024` and `Torus.025` inside collection `3tubev1`

Comment: it would be helpful, if you could provide a simple blend file so we can check out your settings and try out solution proposals.

Comment: I have doubts that this will work with the boolean at the end. Why don't you use the male part to build the female part: duplicate the male, use it shape and invert the wanted faces.

Comment: Hey Chris, I went ahead and edited the OP at the bottom to include a Google Drive link where you should be able to download the file.  Please let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Hey lemon, are you worried that the inverted (red) face will cause issues with boolean modifier?  I should have explained this better but that is just a temporary face that I created to make the custom orientation called "Face".  This face will be removed before the modifier so that way all the object's face normals will face outward (blue)

Comment: I'm not worried about that. You have the alignment problem plus the rotation eventually when the two parts are face to face. And the good initial shape can be easily done to have both female and male parts from it (so why boolean?)

Comment: What I meant is this profile on right allows to extrude male and female on left: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBk1N.png

Comment: I think I see what you are saying lemon.  You are saying create the male and female from the same cylinder and then simply separating them?  That way there is no need for boolean.  But my only concern with this is that eventually, I will need to attach the joints to the body of the curved segment.  Wouldn't I have the same alignment/rotation problem once I reach this step?

Comment: More exactly, I meant you can extrude male/female separately from the disk. The curve part could be made after that, I think. But we have no information about the wanted curve (curvature) and what are the 8 parts you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  The 8 parts are eight segments with 45-degree archs.  Each segment has a male end and a female end, so 8 segments can be fitted together to form a complete circle.  After extruding the male/female ends, would you use the spin tool to create the 45-degree arch body?  Or would you recommend a different technique?

Comment: rapidly done for the principle: https://blend-exchange.com/b/BVzdSad9/

Comment: I aspire to your skill level, sir. I would have never thought to do it like this, but I am going to learn more about array and curve modifiers today. But is it safe to say that the alignment approach in the OP is not quite yet possible in the current version of Blender, or at least it is too difficult, and I should have sought out another approach?

Comment: That's my opinion (at least!)...

Comment: Thank you, lemon.  You are doing god's work.  I've upvoted the appropriate comments that can hopefully help others!